# how to create this type linked list

Tags: c

```
// this is program designed to create Cd data base

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//=============================================
//LINKED LIST USED FOR CREATING THE DATABASE CD
//=============================================
struct CD_type_node
{
   int CDnum;
   char title[20];
   int CDcount;
   struct CD_type_node* next;
};

struct Artist_type_node // to create a linked list of CD's
{
   struct CD_type_node CD_data;
   char Artist_name[20];
   struct Artist_type_node* next;
};
```

this is partial of the project:
1) Create a CD_type_node structure having the following fields:

- CD number
- CD title
- CD count
- A pointer to CD_type_node to point to next CD.

2) Create a Artist_type_node structure having the following fields:

- Artist’s name
- A pointer to a CD_type_node, to enable you to create a linked list
  for CDs.

3) In your main, create an array of type Artist_type_nodes that can store up to 100 elements.

Thus, your database will be an array of 100 Artists, where each Artist has a list of CDs. Basically, each Artist’s name and a pointer to the list of CD’s will be stored in the Artist_Array.

---

when i compile this is what it tells me: struct CD_type_node has no element Artist_name

how do i make the correct linked list and how do i create the array

Comment: Well. Add `Artist_name` to `CD_type_node` then ; it's currently a member of `Artist_type_node`

Comment: You will need to post the code that uses these structures.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but I'd recommend you read a good book on the C programming language. Maybe K&R's book, or Deitel & Deitel's.

Answer (score 1):

> when i compile this is what it tells me: struct CD_type_node has no
>   element Artist_name

Well, from what you've shown `CD_type_node` indeed doesn't have a field called `Artist_name`. Perhaps you are **confusing a `CD_type_node` with an `Artist_type_node` object** ?

Comment: yea but how do i create what has been specifide.. i thought i was doing it right?

Comment: @user793384 demotivational: who said you were doing it right ? Do what Oli Charlesworth said in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Either add a string Artist_name to CD_type_node, or add a pointer to the parent Artist_type_node so you save memory. Now to achieve this first make a declaration of Artist_type_node, then implement CD_type_node and then write the implementation of Artist_type_node. To use this structure lets say you're viewing some CD_type_node and want the Artist name , you then create a new Artist_type_node and assign the pointer to it. Read the value and delete the new Artist_type_node OR have some global Artist_type_node and keep switching its pointer - but that's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is program designed to create Cd data base

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//=============================================
//LINKED LIST USED FOR CREATING THE DATABASE CD
//=============================================
struct CD_type_node
{
   int CDnum;
   char title[20];
   int CDcount;
   struct CD_type_node* next;
};

struct Artist_type_node // to create a linked list of CD's
{
   struct CD_type_node* CD_node;
   char Artist_name[20];
};

int main()
{
    struct Artist_type_node artists[100];
}
```

Change your Artist_type_node as I have shown.

Edit: Be sure to read carefully, because it explains to do this in your homework.